# Cannot locate image ressource wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm coding a C# application using WPF

i've a problem when i add a picture as resource in my project and use it as background for some items, in the execution i've an exception in the fonction InitializeComponent();

```
IOException : Cannot locate resource 'ressources/images/avatar-medecins_0.jpg'.
```

the image is located in the folder ressources/images and i already set it as ressource for the app
this problem occurs with any picture i use !

[image]

[image]

Comment: my question was marked as duplicate, but when i saw the answers in the question, i've already done what they said and it doesn't work !

Comment: So you mean there is a folder `ressources` (with double s) in your Visual Studio project, with a subfolder called `images`, and there is a file named `avatar-medecins_0.jpg` which has its Build Action set to `Resource`? Then how are you actually trying to use or load that image file?

Comment: i use the  avatar-medecins_0.jpg image as  background of an ellipse. the image is loaded in the designer viewer, but while runing i've this exception
( and ressource with double s, because it is french ^^ )

Comment: And is the folder structure `ressources/images/avatar-medecins_0.jpg` or just `ressources/avatar-medecins_0.jpg`, as implied by *"the image is located in the folder ressource"* ?

Comment: yes ressources/images sorry ^^ there is no problem of Path, i've all checked ! the image is already here since the Designer Viewer shows it !